# Spliting addresses into 2 columns on house number and street name

Tags: sql, select, oracle-sqldeveloper

If I am writing a query that is returning a list of addresses (the street number and the street name) but those values are stored in the same column, is there a way to split number and street name into 2 different columns?

exp:

```
select address
from customer
```

desired results:

```
123 | any st
345 | some st
```

is this 'easily' possible?

I only have read access, and nothing is going to be changed in the database; it is 'as is'

Comment: oracle functions substr and instr would do it. Personally though I'd have an address table with columns for each bit of the address I wanted to deal with.

Comment: show an example data of address column. what's the delimiter?

Comment: changing the collums is not an option for me; I only have read access. The collumns are as is

Comment: Be careful about this.  Not all addresses are in the format you expect.  You might get values like "10-1 some st" or "1 some st Apr 10".  To me, those have the same meaninig.

Comment: For international addresses house "numbers" even need not be numbers at all; or they may be decorated like "35a" or "3-5", may be separated by comma, blank or other separators, may be in front or at the end of the street name and whatever you can imagine. So I would say there is no easy (and secure) way.

Comment: @DanBracuk is correct, if you are attempting to build an address parsing engine, you're going to have some headaches.  "Chelsea 82 toth street" and "102 1/2 west 43rd avenue" and the above are only a few of the different ways addresses can appear, and are completely standard as far as the USPS is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
IGNORE THIS ANSWER: i've just noticed its for Oracle :(

add this function to your database

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

source http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

and the sql should be:

```
select SPLIT_STR(address,' ',1) as address_num, SPLIT_STR(address,' ',2) as address_desc from customer
```

but the separator should be some unique char or string, as ' ' space might be part of address already.